# Find array value by string key

Tags: php, arrays

I have the current array:

```
$types = array(
    "Rifle" => "rifle",
    "SMG" => "smg",
    "Knife" => "knife",
    "Sticker" => "sticker",
    "Container" => "case",
    "Key" => "key",
    "Shotgun" => "heavy",
    "Machinegun" => "heavy",
    "Music Kit" => "music",
    "Graffiti" => "graffiti",
    "Tag" => "tag",
);
```

I'm then wanting to check if my string contains the word from one of the keys, for example "Covert Rifle" should match the first element in the array and return "rifle".

"My Big Container" should then match "Container" and return "case".

Trying to use

```
array_search("My Big Container", $types);
```

This doesn't return anything and is FALSE. I take it because my keys are not numerical and are instead strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
function getArrayValueBasedOnString($array, $string, $caseSensitive = false){
  $s = $caseSensitive ? '' : 'i';
  foreach($array as $k => $v){
    if(preg_match('/'.preg_quote($k, '/')."/$s", $string)){
      return $v;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
$result = getArrayValueBasedOnString($types, 'My Big Container');
```

Of course, this will return the very first match. And if you have any `null` `$array` values you might want to change that return value.

Comment: You should consider preg_quote to escape reserved values of the regex.

Comment: Of course, I concur, if you have any weird array keys.

Answer (score 1):

`array_search` is searching for values.
If you want to search for the keys, you should transform keys to values using `array_keys`

```
$key = array_search("Container", array_keys($types));
if( is_array($key) && count($key) > 0 )
    return $types[$key];
```

However, array_search will perform an exact match. If you want partial match (one word) or case insensitive or else, then you should not use `array_search` but loop over all keys and try to find any word

```
$keys = array_keys($types);
$words = explode(" ", "My Big Container");
$match = null;
foreach( $keys as $k )
    foreach( $words as $w )
        if( $k == $w ) $match = $w;

if( $match !== null )
    return $types[$match];
```

Comment: This will definitely be a multi word search (and potentially case sensitive). What alternative do I have for array_search?

Comment: I included a (simple) example of multi word search